# Trying to add 2 extra cells to collection view "Add more" and "Placeholder"

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

For some reason my collection view wont return the correct number of items. I am trying to add 2 placeholder cells in my collection view so I add an extra 2 to my array count.

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if IGAccounts.isEmpty {
        print("its empty")
        return 2
    } else {
        print("its not empty: \(IGAccounts.count)")
        return IGAccounts.count + 2
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    print("should be called three times")
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "IGLoginCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! IGLoginCollectionViewCell

    if IGAccounts.isEmpty {
        if indexPath.item == 0 {
            cell.type = .Login
        } else if indexPath.item == 1 {
            cell.type = .Placeholder
        }
    } else {
        print("the count: \(IGAccounts.count) the row: \(indexPath.item)")
        if indexPath.item == IGAccounts.count + 1 {
            cell.type = .Add
        } else if indexPath.item == IGAccounts.count {
            cell.type = .Placeholder
        } else {
            cell.type = .Created
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

This is the log after loading the View controller and adding an account:

```
its empty
its empty
should be called three times
should be called three times
push IG login
its not empty: 1
should be called three times
the count: 1 the row: 0
should be called three times
the count: 1 the row: 1
```

Been stuck on this for a few hours. If anyone has any idea what im doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you add screenshots of simulator.

Comment: @Arasuvel the content view of the collection view is correctly sized. Is that what you were hoping to see?